# can't debug bash scripts using VSCode

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code, sh

I've installed VSCode with Bash debug extension.

Before that, I've installed `bashdb` and I've verified its version using `bashdb --version` and it's 4.4.

Now, the extension creates an empty file called `launch.json`.

I wrote the following to start debugging, but still, nothing happened

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
   
    "scriptPath": "${command:SelectScriptName}",
 
    "configurations": [
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "type": "bashdb",
            "name": "Compound",
            "configurations": []
        }
    ]
}
```

What should I do to enable debugging?

Answer (score 0):

With the `bashdb` extension installed, add the following block to the `launch.json` file. This configuration allows you to debug the script you have currently open on VS Code. So, in order to start debugging a script you must have it open on VS Code, and type `F5` to start debugging it. Alternatively, and also with the same script open on VS Code, you can open the `Run and Debug` menu, on the VS Code left bar, and click `Play`.

```
{
  "type": "bashdb",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Bash-Debug (simplest configuration)",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "program": "${file}",
  "showDebugOutput": true,
  "terminalKind": "integrated"
}
```

Adding the `args`  parameter to the above block, allows you to pass an array with arguments to the script while debugging.

Answer (score -1):

I tested this code with the Bash Debug extension:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": 
  [
    {
        "type": "bashdb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Bash-Debug (select script from list of sh files)",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "program": "${command:SelectScriptName}",
        "args": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Visual Studio Code displays a list of scripts from your project, and you can pick the one you want to run. You can alternatively choose a "Bash-Debug (hardcoded script name)" configuration, which allows to hardcode the script path.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to debug a Bash script I recommend you execute your script with -x flag. For example:

```
bash -x script.sh
```

or into the script add:

```
set -x 
<DEBUG_CODE_LINES>
set +x
```

Comment: I know this option. I'm trying to use VSCode